# Python __str__: Magic Console

Tags: python

Suppose one decided (yes, this is horrible) to create handle input in the following manner: A user types in a command on the python console after importing your class, the command is actually a class name, the class name's `__str__` function is actually a function with side effects (e.g. the command is "north" and the function changes some global variables and then returns text describing your current location).  Obviously this is a stupid thing to do, but how would you do it (if possible)?

Note that the basic question is how to define the `__str__` method for a class without creating an instance of the class, otherwise it would be simple (but still just as crazy:

```
class ff:
    def __str__(self):
        #do fun side effects
        return "fun text string"

ginst = ff()

>>ginst
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is the metaclass

```
class Magic(type):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Something crazy'
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Another craziness'

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = Magic

>>> print Foo
Something crazy
>>> Foo
Another craziness
```

Comment: in py3k you'd need to pass `metaclass` as a keyword: `class Bar(metaclass=Magic): pass` for this method to work.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

in console you're getting representation of your object, which `__repr__` is responsible for. `__str__` used for printing:

```
>>> class A:
    def __str__(self):
        return 'spam'


>>> A()
<__main__.A object at 0x0107E3D0>
>>> print(A())
spam

>>> class B:
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'ham'


>>> B()
ham
>>> print(B())
ham

>>> class C:
    def __str__(self):
        return 'spam'
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'ham'


>>> C()
ham
>>> print(C())
spam
```

Comment: You are still instantiating the class, though. That's not what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use instances of a class rather than classes themselves.  Something like

```
class MagicConsole(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.__f = f

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__f()

north = MagicConsole(some_function_for_north)
south = MagicConsole(some_function_for_south)
# etc
```